# Hyperlink Browser inside other browsers

Tags: browser

for Example if i want open a website with Edge browser inside other browsers i use command in other browsers URL :

```
microsoft-edge:http://example.com
```

after enter this command automatically Edge browser open .
but for open other browsers (Firefox and Chrome and Safari and IE ) What command should I use?

Edge -->  microsoft-edge:http://example.com

Firefox --> ???:http://example.com

Chrome --> ???:http://example.com

Safari --> ???:http://example.com

IE --> ???:http://example.com

---

i check another Program , for open Telegram Desktop app (if Telegram Desktop app installed on the OS ) , if you write keyword *"tg:"* inside any browser Address Bar and press enter , Telegram App open .

My question is, by writing which keyword in the Google Chrome Address Bar, the Firefox program will be called and opened separately.

Comment: That is a recipe for failure. Open the browsers independently, or use a virtual machine for a different browser

Comment: @John if this command is a recipe for failure , This order was never made . If this command was not used, the browser designers would not have included it

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you cannot run one browser connected to a website inside another browser in a generalized way. That is not going to work. What you are asking is not like a browser window inside the same browser on a weblink designed to work this way.

Comment: @John I do not intend to do this at all. I just want to call another browser separately with a command inside the browser.

Comment: I have never (ever) seen that done before. Not ever.

Answer (score 0):

In most modern OSes, you can register protocols to be handled by a specific app. You can see an example of this in [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows), and you can read more about in the [Group Policy documentation](https://admx.help/?Category=Chrome&Policy=Google.Policies.Chrome::RegisteredProtocolHandlers_recommended). In this case, Microsoft decided to include a custom protocol handler to open Microsoft Edge, presumably so they could make links that specifically open in Microsoft Edge on Windows devices. The other major browsers do not appear to do this by default, but for your own personal computer, you can register custom protocol handlers, which should cause any browser on the OS to open browser-specific links correctly. Note that other OSes may not honor `microsoft-edge` as a protocol (notably, because Edge doesn't exist on most other OSes). Browsers themselves also allow registration of custom protocols via [Navigator.registerProtocolHandler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler), although this support is only for web apps.

Comment: I can guarantee you that no other operating system will honor the `microsoft-edge` protocol.  To my knowledge the other browsers are incapable of registering their own protocol.

Comment: @Ramhound What I found surprising is that there is actually a [large number of OSes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-supported-operating-systems) edge can run on. I never looked into it before. Technically, other browsers can register custom protocols (it's a shell feature), I guess they just choose not to. Honestly, I don't think that edge should have its own custom protocol, but Microsoft has always been the one to have questionable ethics regarding stuff like this.

Comment: @ana Yes, the developer of any app can choose to have their own protocols. This is really prominent in the mobile space (e.g. Reddit will open the Reddit app on your phone if you have it installed), and a lot of desktop apps like Zoom also do this. I can't seem to find a reason for the other browsers not registering their own protocols; it's not a technical limitation, I guess they just don't feel the need to force links to their own browser. But, as I said here, if you want your own custom protocol handler, you can do so yourself on your own devices.

Comment: Edge on other operating systems other than Windows is just a rebranded Chromium browser.  Linux and macOS don't support registering URL protocols to my knowledge. Chrome and Firefox might have their own URL protocol, I just don't know it, only thing Microsoft prevents is using the microsoft-edge protocol to launch anything except Edge.